# bash find command not giving the output i would expect

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Im trying to get the hang of the command find but im kind of confused as to why i get this kind of output from this code can anyone explain?
Output:

```
file1
file2
file3
etc...
good morning
```

What i want is

```
file1
good morning
file2
good morning
file3
good morning
```

etc....

```
for line in `find $1 -type f`
do  
    echo $line
    echo hello good morning                     
done
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for cleaning that up =p

Comment: As it is, this code should work. Are you running it from a file?

Comment: neither your actual output nor your expected output matches your code. Please post the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

You code should work. This is another way to try it:
find . -type f -exec echo -e {}"\n" good morning \;

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
find $1 -type f -print -exec echo good morning \;
```

or even shorter if you have gnu-find

```
find $1 -type f -printf "%p\ngoog morning\n"
```